# Writing a fraction as $x^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, fractions

I came across this  fraction after practising with bunch for a while. How do I write this fraction
$$1\over x^a$$
as
$$x^n$$
What happens to the $a$? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

By definition:
$$\frac1{x^a}=x^{-a}$$
So $n=-a$. The $x^{-a}$ form is usually used when there arises the need to save space.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x^a}=\frac{x^0}{x^a}=x^{0-a}=x^{-a}$$

Answer (score 2):

As $\frac {1}{x}=x^{-1}$, we can see that $\frac {1}{x^a}=(x^{-1})^a$, which can be simplified to $x^{-a}$. Note; $1^a = 1, (x^m)^n=x^{mn}$

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $n$ such that
$$x^n=\frac{1}{x^a}$$
$$x^nx^a=1$$
$$x^{n+a}=1$$
So, you have to take $n$ such that $n+a=0$, i.e. $n=-a$.